# Get selected text in an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get the selected text in an input box of a website, using either jQuery or vanilla JavaScript?

I have tried with `var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();`,
but this code only gets the text in a **paragraph** and not in an **input box**.

---

EDIT: Maybe I was unclear, I want to get the text from a website that I didn't create. I'm building a Chrome extension and I need to get the text from an input box of a website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```js
function showSelectedText() {
  var input = document.getElementById('text');
  var selection = text.value.substring(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd);
  alert(selection);
}
```

```html
<input id="text" value="Hello, how are you?"><br>
<button onclick="showSelectedText()">Show selected text</button>
```

Comment: maybe I was unclear, I want to get the text from a website that I didn't creat. I'm building a chrome extension and I need to get the text from input box of a website.

Comment: This general approach is good, although `input.value.substring()` is preferable to `text.value.substr()`, which is a "legacy" function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jQuery plugins you can accomplish that by using this one http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/

It's flexible (You can use it both for inputs and for paragraphs)