How to display selected text inside MathQuill in the console?
I need to display any content selected in MathQuill in the console. I tried using getSelection(), but it didn't work. Any other official way to achieve this?
I tried the following:
mathquillDidMount = {(mathField) => {
  mathFieldRef.current = mathField;
}}


Given that you're working with a normal input element, then the standard method of retrieving text selection should work, eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809197/519413. The fact that MathQuill has been instantiated on it should not affect this
